# Best MVC approach when passing objects to a view from a controller? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have three tables: User, Task, and UserTask (which has User and Task as foreign keys, no other columns). An entry in the UserTask table *may or may not exist* for a particular User/Task combination (UserTask records are created as needed for scalability reasons).

In my view, I'd like to show all Tasks for the currently logged in User. For each Task, I want to display the text "yes" if a corresponding record exists in the UserTask table; otherwise I want to display "no". But I'm a bit unsure of what objects I should pass to the view from the controller, and how I should interact with objects (i.e. what I am allowed to do) once they are passed to the view.

Should I pass the User, Tasks, and UserTasks as separate variables from the controller to the view? This way, I can show all Tasks by simply iterating through the Tasks variable, and for each Task I can use a `where` (ActiveRecord query) in the view to determine whether there is a UserTask for each Task. Thing is, is it okay to do `where` and `find` queries on object passed into a view? I always assumed you leave that to the controller and only do simple things in the view, like iteration over objects passed to the view (correct me if that is wrong).

Or should I build a Hash in the controller where each key is a Task and each value is a UserTask, and then pass that Hash to the view? This way, I can show all Tasks in the view by simply iterating through all of the keys, and for each Task key I can display "yes" or "no" by checking whether the value is null or not.

Or is there another way (i.e. joining tables or something... not sure how that would work)?

Comment: Actually, if you were to follow Model2 MVC or HMVC, the view should be retrieving information from model layer. Then again .. if you were really strict about following MVC patterns, you would not be using active record (anti)pattern either.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really read up on associations in rails:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

The way you intend to set up the relationship between users and tasks strikes me as a bit odd, but putting that aside, to implement it as you've described it you would define associations on your `User`, `Task` and `UserTask` models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_task
end

class UserTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end
```

In your controller:

```
@user = User.includes(:user_tasks).find(...)
@tasks = Task.all
```

Then, in your view (in haml):

```
-@tasks.each do |task|
  =(@user.user_tasks.include?(task)) ? "yes" : "no"
```

EDIT: Updated according to explanation in comments.

Comment: In my scenario, Task does not belong to User and a User does not have many Tasks. How would it work in that case?

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing it that way. If you want to get the tasks associated with a user, then you should have an association between the two models. What do you mean, a User does not have "many" Tasks?

Comment: Oh I think I understand. So you mean that you want to iterate through *all* tasks and display "yes" if a task is associated with `@user` through a UserTask, and "no" otherwise?